# Property of projective modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, let $P$ be a projective and finitely generated $R$-module, and let $(M_\alpha)_{\alpha}$ be a (possibly infinite) family of $R$-modules. I want to prove that the canonical map
$$(\prod_\alpha M_\alpha) \otimes_R P \to \prod_\alpha M_\alpha \otimes P,$$
$$(m_\alpha)_\alpha \otimes_R p \mapsto (m_\alpha \otimes p)_\alpha,$$
is an isomorphism.

*Attempt:* The claim holds if $P = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k R$ is a free and finitely generated $R$-module, since then 
$$(\prod_\alpha M_\alpha) \otimes_R P = (\prod_\alpha M_\alpha) \otimes_R (\bigoplus_{i=1}^k R) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^k (\prod_\alpha M_\alpha) \otimes_R R  \cong $$
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \prod_\alpha M_\alpha \cong \prod_\alpha \bigoplus_{i=1}^k M_\alpha \otimes_R R \cong \prod_\alpha M_\alpha \otimes_R P.$$
Further, the above map is clearly natural in $P$. According to the literature, this observation should imply that the claim holds for projective finitely generated $P$, but I do not see how. Could anybody help me please? (Any definition of a projective module can be used here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P\oplus Q=R^k$. Then you have a split exact sequence $0\to P\to R^k\to Q\to0$ which produces the commutative diagram with split exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> 
\Bigl(\prod_\alpha M_\alpha\Bigr) \otimes_R P @>>>
\Bigl(\prod_\alpha M_\alpha\Bigr) \otimes_R R^k @>>>
\Bigl(\prod_\alpha M_\alpha\Bigr) \otimes_R Q @>>>
0
\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>>
\prod_\alpha (M_\alpha \otimes P) @>>>
\prod_\alpha (M_\alpha \otimes R^k) @>>>
\prod_\alpha (M_\alpha \otimes Q) @>>>
0
\end{CD}
$$
where the middle vertical row is an isomorphism. A simple diagram chasing shows that that the left and right arrows are, respectively, injective and surjective.

Exchange the roles of $P$ and $Q$.